# Value error when using genfromtxt in python

Tags: python, csv

Not sure why I am getting a value error. My csv file seems to be fine. The last lines of the error message Line #_ (got 8 columns instead of 2) is given for all lines of my file. What could be wrong?

Edit to add more info about the csv file:

8 columns and about 170 rows. first and last column areempty ( filled with "") besides the header.
ex.

```
DeID,localid,YOB,Age,race,gender,indication,Freq of Unique Codes
,1000015126,1948,68,White,M,None,
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-934d1d311b14> in <module>
      1 # create array of info
----> 2 info = np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Users\khana\Documents\list.csv', delimiter=',',skip_header=0)
      3 


~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows, encoding)
   2101             # Raise an exception ?
   2102             if invalid_raise:
-> 2103                 raise ValueError(errmsg)
   2104             # Issue a warning ?
   2105             else:

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 8 columns instead of 2)
    Line #3 (got 8 columns instead of 2)
```

Comment: it seems it is not correct CSV - maybe header has only 2 names but later you have 8 values in rows. Or it uses `,` in text but code treats it as separator. Better show what you have in CSV file.

Comment: I have no problem to read example data using `np.genfromtxt` or `pandas.read_csv()` . You would have to check if you really read the same data from file. You could read it as normal text and display `print( open(r'C:\Users\khana\Documents\list.csv').read() )`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

I used to receive such error during the following cases (some data engineer)

1. There could be an EOL(end of line) character in of those columns values. Like `\n` or `\r` or both. Please explore them. Checking like 7 and 8, if you get error.
2. In CSV, it is possible to read multi-line values using an escape character. You check `CSV` module documentation.
3. Like EOL, there could also few colens, single quotes, double quotes, tabs, empty spaces, non-ascii characters, hexa digits.. etc
4. The file could be just corrupted!

(Last 2 are not related to your question, but just added as guidance checks to lookout when read csv files)